# Generate gmail-attachment url to view

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I'm working on project which can access all the pictures in g-mail.I've tried the G-mail API using node which can fetch all required attachments.But that requires to download the whole image.I can access the attachment id and message id using the API.Is there any way to generate the url of attachment (to view) so that i can provide a link to the required image from my project.

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found this related issue, [Issue #134](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166981/generate-gmail-attachment-url-to-view), and you may want to try the suggested solution.

You may fetch email attachments using this:

> `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik={ik_value}&view=att&th={message_id}&attid=0.{atachment_index}&disp=safe&zw`
>
> wherein, `attachmment_index` is just the index of the attachment. If there are 3 attachments and you want to get the 3rd file, the index value will be `3`. This URL is a 302 header that acts like a link shortener for the download file. Opening this link will lead you to the attachment data

```
var ik = gmail.tracker.ik;
var id = gmail.get.email_id();
var aid = "1"; // gets the first attachment

var url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=" + ik + "&view=att&th=" + id + "&attid=0." + aid + "&disp=safe&zw";

console.log(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, i 've already seen issue #134 & was able to generate the link to download the attachment but i dont need to download the image, i just need a link to view the image that too without authentication. is there anyway i could authenticate with oauth2client to generate a link to attachment (using gmail api)