# How to Find the Attachment ID for Getting an Email Using the Gmail API?

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

I use Python to access Gmail via the Gmail-API. I want to make a simple call to download the attachment of an email and for this you have to pass three parameters: ID, message ID and UserID. I have the last two, but where do I find the first? The Doc says that it's the ID of the attachment so I tried the option "show original" in Gmail, but with no success. The API keeps returning the error message "invalid attachment token". Where do I find the attachment ID?

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get

Comment: Did you look up on accessing the attachment via its index [gmail attachment via index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166981/generate-gmail-attachment-url-to-view) ?

Comment: Yes, but i don't understand the solution. Executing the code in the console doesn't work. Opening the link via Firefox neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to retrieve the the `ID` of the attachments of a certain message, you would have to get the message resource via [Users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get), and from that response, retrieve the `ID` of the attachment.

This `ID` can be found in the `body` property of [the corresponding message part](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments#resource) (you can use properties like `filename` to know which attachment corresponds to each `ID`), as shown in this sample:

```js
{
  "payload": {
    "parts": [
      {
        "filename": {attachment_filename},
        "body": {
          "attachmentId": {attachment_id}
          // other body properties
        },
        // other part properties
      },
      // other parts
    ],
    // other payload properties
  },
  // other message properties
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)
- [Users.messages.attachments](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments#resource)